# Перегрузка операции ==

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть класс и у него перегружена операция ==

```
bool operator== (StringСustomize *b) {
    return isQually(this, b);
}

    bool isQually(StringСustomize *a, StringСustomize *b) {
    if (a->length() == b->length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a->length(); i++) {
            if (a->str[i] != b->str[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

И есть проблема

```
std::cout << (t->isQually(t,t1) ? "True" : "false"); // TRUE
std::cout << (t == t1 ? "True" : "false"); // FALSE
```

При условии что t и t1 равны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду у вас `t` и `t1` - **указатели**, а оператор `==` перегружен для `StringСustomize&` и `StringСustomize*`.

В `t == t1` вы сравниваете два указателя, которые, конечно же, не равны.

Сравнивайте тогда уж так: `*t == t1` или `t->operator==(t1)`.